# Странная работа print() с параметром end

Tags: python

```
from time import sleep

print('2 + ', end='')
sleep(1)
print('2 = ', end='')
sleep(1)
print('4')
```

Почему при вручную заданном значении `end` печать будет производиться лишь при достижении 7 строки, но если оставить его стандартным или вписать `end='\n'`, то все будет работать так, как задумывалось?

Comment: Да, вывод буферизуется по строкам. Нужно дописать опцию `flush=True` чтобы отключить это

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как сказал [@andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal), вывод буферизуется по строкам, можно либо добавлять `flush=True` в `print`, либо установить переменную окружения `export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` чтобы достичь того же эффекта но глобально.

Также можно запускать так: `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 python main.py`